# Makefile Creation Difficulty

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation

I had to merge two codes **(TestOne.cpp + TestTwo.cpp)**, one of them already has its makefile **(TestOne.cpp)**, but the other has only .h included, each of these .h has no cpp, all the code is on the .h **(TestTwo.cpp)**

for the makefile it's like this , and it work:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11

test: main.o hung.o
     $(CC) -o test main.o hung.o

hung.o: Hungarian.cpp Hungarian.h
     $(CC) -c Hungarian.cpp -o hung.o

main.o: testMain.cpp Hungarian.h
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c testMain.cpp -o main.o

clean:
    -rm main.o hung.o
```

and the other one **(TestTwo.cpp)** it's also work by compiling like that :

```
g++ TestTwo.cpp -o test `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

I have to create a new makefile using the first and introducing the seconde commande g++ ... how should i do ?

Comment: If all the code is in the header you don't need to introduce something new in the makefile. Just including the header from the sources is sufficient. May be add another dependency for the `.h` file for the source rules. Or did I understand your question wrong?

Comment: i tried to add the opencv LIBS, and on the main.o : i add all the .h ... is that what you mean ?

Comment: If you want to add the opencv libs to that existing makefile change the line for linking: `$(CC) -o test main.o hung.o \`pkg-config opencv --libs\``

Comment: Both executable files have the same name: `test`. Do you want that? Perhaps they could better be named `test1` and `test2`.

Comment: Thank you for the remark , yes i'll change the names !